# How to convert "sensor" names to a /sys path?

Tags: fan, temperature, devices, fancontrol

Programs such as `sensor` list sensors by name, such as `package ID 0` and `core 0`.  However, `/etc/fancontrol` uses things like `/sys/device/...`.  How do I figure out the path from the name?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in /etc/sensors3.conf.  This is where sensors will label and convert many of the values in /sys/devices/platform/* to what you see in the sensors output.  You may also be able to find custom entries on the internet for your motherboard, and could even create your own if you know how.

For instance, my board is nct6791-isa-0290 and there is a default entry for  "nct6791-*" already in /etc/sensors.conf.  After searching around, I found several versions of other configs for my motherboard out there, like this thread that discusses how it was generated.  http://www.spinics.net/lists/lm-sensors/msg42249.html

Comment: On my system, `sensors` shows one called `Package id 0`.  I looked in `/etc/sensors3.conf` but I do not see anything like that -- not even a partial match.  Under `psensor`, I see the same name.  If I right-click on it and look at details, it describes it as `lmsensor coretemp-isa-0000`, but again I do not see anything obvious in the `.conf` file.  Is there another place to look for definitions?  Thanks.

Comment: What you see in coretemp is hard coded into the driver.  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.c

Comment: Thanks, this led me to the answer.  For example, `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon1` has various files `temp*_*` -- and the `*_label` for each is the label used by `sensors` and `psensor`.  For example, on my system `temp1_label` is `Physical id 0`, `temp2_label` is `Core 0`, and so on.  So I can read the `_label` file and that tells me the corresponding `/sys/device/...` to use.